# Typescript: Use strings from a list of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript, string

I have a use case of performing an API call, which accepts parameters like this:

```
api('str1', 'str2', 'str3');
```

I don't want to hardcode all parameters so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
const LIST: string[] = ['list-item-1', 'list-item-2'];

api('str1-hardcoded', LIST.join(','))
```

But this does not solve the issue, as join produces a **single string** from all items which is not what I want.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need use `...`

```js
const LIST: string[] = ['list-item-1', 'list-item-2'];

api('str1-hardcoded', ...LIST)
```